# autorelease not very clear

Tags: iphone, ios

I am not too clear about the autorelease message...
When autorelease is sent to an object, what does it mean "only until the end of the event loop" does the object gets released?
Why can't the end of the event loop occur right in the between of autorelease and the expected retain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The framework calls your code as part of event loop processing for events where you've indicated some interest (a button clicked, a view loaded, a notification delivered, etc...).  The end of that event loop happens after you return from that processing and let the framework do whatever it needs to next.  So, it isn't going to drain the pool until your code gives control back.

(This sequence of events is also an approximate explanation for why physical screen updates don't occur if user code is stuck in a processing loop.)